# load html mail file inside php

Tags: php, html, email

I implemented a html email inside a html file. And i have a php file which uses the `PHPMailer` class to send emails.
What i want to achieve is, i have some text inside the html that should change depends who i send the email.

This is the php file that sends the emails

```
<?php
    // get variables
    $contact_name = addslashes($_GET['contact_name']);
    $contact_phone = addslashes($_GET['contact_phone']);
    $contact_email = addslashes($_GET['contact_email']);
    $contact_message = addslashes($_GET['contact_message']);

    // send mail
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $mailer->IsSMTP();
    $mailer->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465';
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    $mailer->Username = 'danyel.p@gmail.com';
    $mailer->Password = 'mypass';
    $mailer->From = 'contact_email';
    $mailer->FromName = 'PS Contact';
    $mailer->Subject = $contact_name;
    $mailer->AddAddress('pdaniel@gmail.com');
    $mailer->Body = $contact_message;
    if($mailer->Send())
        echo 'ok';
?>
```

And the html file containing a simple html mail implemented with tables and all that standard it need.

I want to ask braver minds than mine which is the best approach to accomplish this. :)

Thank you in advance,
Daniel!

EDIT: right now, in the $mailer->Body i have the $contact_message variable as a text email.. but i want in that body to load an html file containing an html email and i want to somehow change the body of the html email with the text inside this $contact_message variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to go is to have special tokens in your html files that will be replaced by the caller. For example assuming that you have two variables that might dynamically change content, `name`, `surname` then put something like this in your html: `%%NAME%%`, `%%SURNAME%%` and then in the calling script simply:

```
$html = str_replace("%%NAME%%", $name, $html);
$html = str_replace("%%SURNAME%%", $surname, $html);
```

or by nesting the two above:

```
$html = str_replace("%%NAME%%", $name, str_replace("%%SURNAME%%", $surname, $html));
```

**EDIT**
A more elegant solution in case you have many variables: Define an associative array that will hold your *needles* and *replacements* for them:

```
$myReplacements = array ( "%%NAME%%"    => $name,
                          "%%SURNAME%%" => $surname
);
```

and use a loop to make it happen:

```
foreach ($myReplacements as $needle => $replacement)
   $html = str_replace($needle, $replacement, $html);
```

Comment: i like your approach very much :) now there is only 1 more step to make it happen :D how to load the html file's content into php

Comment: Simply again by $html = file_get_contents("/path/to/myHtmlFile.html");

Comment: If you go this with this method, at least do this: http://codepad.org/4xbLFXIB instead of calling str_replace for every "replacement" you have.

Comment: this approach is just too cool :) i am trying it as we speak and it works just great! Thank you very much pankar and thank you for the parameters idea tigrang, this approach make it simple to modify stuff later. also thanks to all who posted on this question

Comment: @tigrang +1 for the 1-liner ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create conditional statements based on the email you want to see to.
Then include that in the tempalted php html email text.

You can also pass the changing values to a function which will implement the above.

Answer (score 0):

If I build a website I usually use a templating engine, something like Smarty... You could write your html mail in a smarty template file. Then you could add the wanted texts based on criteria automatically. Just assign the correct values to the templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your edit:

```
function renderHtmlEmail($body) {
    ob_start();
    include ('my_html_email.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

In your `my_html_email.php` file you would have something like so:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>....<p>
        <!-- the body -->
        <?php echo $body; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And

```
 $mailer->Body = renderHtmlEmail($contact_message);
```

If you need other variables to pass to the layout/template file, add params to that method, or pass an associative array like so `function renderHtmlEmail($viewVars)` and inside the function `extract($viewVars);`

You will then be able to use those vars inside the template, for ex. `Dear <?php echo $to; ?>,`

You will probably have to change your html file from .html to .php if it isn't already.

That is, if I understood the issue correctly.